# Для чего приписывать символ F в конце литерала с типом float?

Tags: java, типы-данных, типы

Если с типом для целых чисел long все понятно, L приписываем литералу когда нужно вписать число больше диапазона int. А на счет типа float, если же мы присвоим ему литерал, он автоматически опустится с double до float, ведь значения из float 100% будут входить в значения double, и собственно вопрос, для чего приписывать литералу F, может какой нибудь простой пример подкинете?

Comment: спс исправил, не заметил просто

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Точно так же, как `L` отделяет `long` от `int`, `F` отделяет `float` от `double`.

Просто в Java по-умолчания `double` выбран для чисел с плавающей запятой. К примеру, такое не скомпилится:

```
float myFLoat = 1.5;
```

Пока не допишите литерал:

```
float myFLoat = 1.5f;
```